# Using 2 VL53L4CD ToF sensors and getting error after getting first reading

Tags: sensors, i2c

pretty new to arduino stuff and was hoping to get some help with my code.

I'm trying to use 2 ToF sensors and get continuous readings from them. I understand that I have to use the xshut feature and switch them on and off to alternate them but I'm stuck in an error loop and I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Does anyone know what's going on and how to solve this?

Here's my code:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <vl53l4cd_class.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
//#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#define DEV_I2C Wire
#define SerialPort Serial
char report[64];
//address we will assign if dual sensor is present
uint8_t sensor1add = 0x30;
uint8_t sensor2add = 0x31;
// set the pins to shutdown
#define xshut1 A0
#define xshut2 A1
#define GFX_BL DF_GFX_BL
//this holds the measurement
VL53L4CD_Result_t results1;
VL53L4CD_Result_t results2;
float sensor1, sensor2;
//Components.
VL53L4CD sensor1_vl53l4cd_sat(&DEV_I2C, A0);
VL53L4CD sensor2_vl53l4cd_sat(&DEV_I2C, A1);
//init Wifi
/*void initWifi(){
    Serial.print("Setting AP (Access Point)...");
  // No password
  WiFi.softAP (ssid);
  // Start WiFi Access Point
  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.print(IP);
    // Print ESP8266 Local IP Adress
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}*/
//init sensors
void initSensor(VL53L4CD sensorX, uint8_t sensoradd)
{
  // Init sensor1
  //Set sensor address.
  sensorX.VL53L4CD_SetI2CAddress(sensoradd);
  // Configure VL53L4CD satellite component.
  sensorX.begin();
  // Switch off VL53L4CD satellite component.
  sensorX.VL53L4CD_Off();
  //Initialize VL53L4CD satellite component.
  sensorX.InitSensor();
  // Program the highest possible TimingBudget, without enabling the
  // low power mode. This should give the best accuracy
  sensorX.VL53L4CD_SetRangeTiming(200, 0);
  sensorX.VL53L4CD_SetOffset(-10);
  // Start Measurements
  sensorX.VL53L4CD_StartRanging();
}
//getSensor1Reading
void getSensor1Reading(uint8_t status, uint8_t NewDataReady)
{
  sensor1_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_On();
  Serial.println("Sensor 1 is on");
  if ((!status) && (NewDataReady != 0)) {
    // (Mandatory) Clear HW interrupt to restart measurements
    sensor1_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_ClearInterrupt();
    // Read measured distance. RangeStatus = 0 means valid data
    sensor1_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_GetResult(&results1);
    snprintf(report, sizeof(report), "Status = %3u, Distance = %5u mm, Signal = %6u kcps/spad\r\n",
             results1.range_status,
             results1.distance_mm,
             results1.signal_per_spad_kcps);
    sensor1 = results1.distance_mm;
    Serial.println((String)"This is Sensor1 " + (float)sensor1 + (String)"mm");
  }
  sensor1_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_Off();
}
//getSensor2Reading
void getSensor2Reading(uint8_t status, uint8_t NewDataReady)
{
  sensor2_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_On();
  Serial.println("Sensor 2 is on");
  if ((!status) && (NewDataReady != 0)) {
    // (Mandatory) Clear HW interrupt to restart measurements
    sensor2_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_ClearInterrupt();
    // Read measured distance. RangeStatus = 0 means valid data
    sensor2_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_GetResult(&results2);
    snprintf(report, sizeof(report), "Status = %3u, Distance = %5u mm, Signal = %6u kcps/spad\r\n",
             results2.range_status,
             results2.distance_mm,
             results2.signal_per_spad_kcps);
    sensor2 = results2.distance_mm;
    Serial.println((String)"This is Sensor2 " + (float)sensor2 + (String)"mm");
  }
  sensor2_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_Off();
}
/*void offset()
{
}*/
/* Setup ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void setup()
{
  // Initialize serial for output.
  SerialPort.begin(115200);
  SerialPort.println("Starting...");
  // Initialize I2C bus.
  DEV_I2C.begin();
  
  initSensor(sensor1_vl53l4cd_sat, sensor1add);
  initSensor(sensor2_vl53l4cd_sat, sensor2add);
}
void loop()
{
  uint8_t NewDataReady1 = 0;
  uint8_t NewDataReady2 = 0;
  uint8_t status1;
  uint8_t status2;
  do {
    status1 = sensor1_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_CheckForDataReady(&NewDataReady1);
    status2 = sensor2_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_CheckForDataReady(&NewDataReady2);
  } while (!NewDataReady1 || !NewDataReady2);
  getSensor1Reading(status1, NewDataReady1);
  getSensor2Reading(status2, NewDataReady2);
  if (!sensor1_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_CheckForDataReady(&NewDataReady1))
  {
    Serial.println((String)"NewDataReady1 is not ready");
  }
  else if (!sensor2_vl53l4cd_sat.VL53L4CD_CheckForDataReady(&NewDataReady2))
  {
    Serial.println((String)"NewDataReady2 is not ready");
  }
  else{Serial.println("New data unable to be parsed");}
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
--- forcing DTR inactive
--- forcing RTS inactive
--- Terminal on COM9 | 115200 8-N-1
--- Available filters and text transformations: colorize, debug, default, direct, esp32_exception_decoder, hexlify, log2file, nocontrol, printable, send_on_enter, time
--- More details at https://bit.ly/pio-monitor-filters
--- Quit: Ctrl+C | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H
This is Sensor1 0.00mm
This is Sensor2 30.00mm
[  2883][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error -1
[  3884][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error 263
[  3884][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error -1
[  3886][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error -1
[  3893][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error -1
[  3900][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error -1
[  3907][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error -1
[  3914][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error -1
[  3921][E][Wire.cpp:499] requestFrom(): i2cWriteReadNonStop returned Error -1
```